# Computing mAP in MaskRCNN fails

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, mask-rcnn

I am trying to detect an object using a custom dataset. The images in my dataset are of size 3060x4080. I have created a coco like dataset from makesense.ai. I am trying to check the complete training and testing of my model before finetuning the hyperparameters. The code is currently running on CPU. I am able to train my model with code shown below. But when I run the `evaluate_model` function, I get a Value Error written at the end of code.

```
import os
import sys
import json
import datetime
import numpy as np
import skimage.draw
import mrcnn
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

from mrcnn.visualize import display_instances, display_top_masks
from mrcnn.utils import extract_bboxes
from mrcnn.utils import Dataset
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mrcnn.config import Config
from mrcnn.model import MaskRCNN
from mrcnn import model as modellib, utils

class CocoLikeDataset(utils.Dataset):
    def load_data(self, annotation_json, images_dir): (not sharing the function body for sake of brevity. The function loads data from coco type dataset from a json file.
                
    def load_mask(self, image_id):

dataset_train = CocoLikeDataset()
dataset_train.load_data('switch_dataset/train/labels/Limit_Switch_Dataset.json', 'switch_dataset/train')
dataset_train.prepare()

dataset_val = CocoLikeDataset()
dataset_val.load_data('switch_dataset/val/labels/Limit_Switch_Dataset_val.json', 'switch_dataset/val')
dataset_val.prepare()

dataset = dataset_train
image_ids = dataset.image_ids
for image_id in image_ids:
    image = dataset.load_image(image_id)
    mask, class_ids = dataset.load_mask(image_id)

image_id = 0
image = dataset_train.load_image(image_id)
mask, class_ids = dataset_train.load_mask(image_id)
bbox = extract_bboxes(mask)

class LimitSwitchConfig(Config):
    NAME = "limit_switch_config_coco"
    NUM_CLASSES = 1 + 1
    STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 2
    #DETECTION_MIN_CONFIDENCE = 0.9 # Skip detections with < 90% confidence
    
config = LimitSwitchConfig()
config.display() 

model = mrcnn.model.MaskRCNN(mode='training', model_dir='./', config=config)
model.load_weights(filepath='mask_rcnn_coco.h5', by_name=True, exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc",  "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"])
model.train(train_dataset= dataset_train, val_dataset= dataset_train, learning_rate= config.LEARNING_RATE, epochs=1, layers='heads')

model_path = 'Limit_Switch_mask_rcnn_trained.h5'
model.keras_model.save_weights(model_path)
print("training completed")

class PredictionConfig(Config):
    NAME = "limit_switch_config_coco"
    NUM_CLASSES = 1 + 1
    GPU_COUNT = 1
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 1
 
def evaluate_model(dataset, model, cfg):
    APs = list()
    for image_id in dataset.image_ids:
        image, image_meta, gt_class_id, gt_bbox, gt_mask = load_image_gt(dataset, cfg, image_id, use_mini_mask=False)
        scaled_image = mold_image(image, cfg)
        sample = expand_dims(scaled_image, 0)
        yhat = model.detect(sample, verbose=0)
        r = yhat[0]
        AP, _, _, _ = compute_ap(gt_bbox, gt_class_id, gt_mask, r["rois"], r["class_ids"], r["scores"], r['masks'])
        APs.append(AP)
    mAP = mean(APs)
    return mAP
 

cfg = PredictionConfig()
model = MaskRCNN(mode='inference', model_dir='logs', config=cfg)
model.load_weights('Limit_Switch_mask_rcnn_trained.h5', by_name=True)
train_mAP = evaluate_model(dataset_train, model, cfg)
print("Train mAP: %.3f" % train_mAP)
```

I get following error.

```
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in dot
ValueError: shapes (100,1048576) and (983040,1) not aligned: 1048576 (dim 1) != 983040 (dim 0)
```

My virtual environment is as follows:

```
python - 3.7.0
numpy==1.20.3
scipy==1.4.1
Pillow==8.4.0
cython==0.29.24
matplotlib
scikit-image==0.16.2
tensorflow==2.2.0
keras==2.3.1
opencv-python==4.5.4.60
h5py==2.10.0
imgaug==0.4.0
IPython[all]
```